# How can I search for escaped characters in RavenDb

Tags: ravendb

First, I found [this article](http://daniellang.net/searching-on-string-properties-in-ravendb/) very helpful about search/index in general, and [this one](http://old.ravendb.net/documentation/how-indexes-work) clued me in on proper indexing. So having used the Keyword Analyzer on my description, I am having trouble finding strings with an '*' (asterisk) in the description. For instance, I have many descriptions that start with "* note". So I would like to find:

```
item.Description.StartsWith("*");
```

I have also tried:

```
.Where( x => x.Description.StartsWith( RavenQuery.Escape( "*" ) ) )
```

But that doesn't seem to work. Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 1):

That should actually work, both in StartsWith and without needing to do the escape.
Can you try creating a failing test?